# Need help identifying this set

Tags: set-identification, city

These came in a clear bag labeled with the number 2.  Dated 2011.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was it [10667 Construction](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10667-1)? The date is a little off, but the parts look right.

[image: 10667]

Comment: You beat me by 1 minute! Anyways - all bags have a date of 2011 on them - I guess that's when the current set bags design was made. I have a couple of recent (2015) bags with exactly the same number.

Comment: That looks right! You guys are awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As @Kramii already said, this is [LEGO Juniors set 11067 Construction](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10667-1). Specifically the bag that makes the crane, without the Octogonal base plate (which was likely supplied separately in the box). Based on the picture Kramii posted you can see how to build this part of the set - you put the 6x6 black plate in the wrong place in your picture, it needs to be at the top.